# Make regex stop matching if next optional group exists

Tags: regex, posix

I try to code the following in C (POSIX, ERE).
`regcomp(&regex, pat, REG_EXTENDED)`

The input expression is of format: token1 token2 token3.

- token1, mandatory, is `:alnum:` or * spaces.
- token2, optional and if present, it only contains literal `A`.
- token3, mandatory, always exactly 4 numbers.

My regex looks like this: `([[:alnum:] ]+) (A)? ?([[:digit:]]{4})`

I would like to catch token1,2,3 in group1,2,3 respectively.

example:
what I want: `R2D2 A 2250` -> group1: `R2D2`, group2: `A`, group3: `2250`
what I have: `R2D2 A 2250` -> group1: `R2D2 A`, group3: `2250`

Since POSIX doesn't support `(?...)` and I have to use ERE (regex.h), literal `A` is automatically attributed to group1.

How can stop regex from considering the optional `A` for group1?
I.a.w., how can I stop regex matching before an optional group if that one exists?

Comment: You need a non-greedy quantifier. Unfortunately, ERE doesn't have this. You'll have to use something beside a regexp.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "`:alnum:` or * spaces"? Could you give some examples to clarify?

Comment: @Nick `:alnum:` = Any alphanumerical character, `* spaces` = 0 or more whitespace

Comment: @Barmar Agreed. Wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything trivial in my regex.

Comment: @geohei yeah I get that, but are you saying that token1 can  be either `:alnum:` or 0 or more whitespace (i.e. `BC1` or `"  "`), or it is `:alnum:` with 0 or more whitespace following (i.e. `BC1` or `BC1   `), or `:alnum:` with 0 or more whitespace interspersed (i.e. `BC1` or `B C 1`)?

Comment: @Nick Ah ... indeed, not clear enough. It's option 3, so `:alnum:` with 0 or more whitespace interspersed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can combine two regexp, one with token2 and one without, then combine the resulting groups:

```
$ sed -nE '
    s/(^([[:alnum:] ]+) (A) ([[:digit:]]{4})$)|(^([[:alnum:] ]*[^A]|[[:alnum:] ]*[^ ]A)() ([[:digit:]]{4})$)/(\2\6)(\3\7)(\4\8)/p
' <<EOD
R2D2 1234
R2D2 A 1234
R2D2 A A 1234
R2D2 AB 1234
  A 1234
R2D2 123
EOD
(R2D2)()(1234)
(R2D2)(A)(1234)
(R2D2 A)(A)(1234)
(R2D2 AB)()(1234)
( )(A)(1234)
$
```

The demonstration code above doesn't handle the case of `A 1234` which I guess should be parsed `(A)()(1234)` since sed only allows 9 groups. If it allowed more, I think adding an extra case and combining the extra groups (ie. \2\6\10, \3\7\11, etc) would handle it:

```
|(^( ?A)() ([[:digits:]{4})$)
```

---

It may be simpler just to write code to do:

- if group 2 is empty

  - if group 1 ends with  `A`

    - then strip it and set group 2

Comment: Nice approach I didn't think of. Wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything trivial in my regex. I'll take the option to solve this outside regex. Thanks!